# Cannot cast object with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.map'

Tags: groovy, hashmap, maps

I have a method which returns a map but I am not able to retrieve the same due to the following error:

```
Cannot cast object '{key=value, key=value}' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.Map'
```

The map is initialized as : `Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>()` in the returning method as well as from the calling code.

Comment: And how are you trying to use it?

Comment: The error states, that you get a string. Something along the lines gives you a string or attempted to serialize the value. Without a minimal failing example, we won't be able to help you.  You have to debug further, where this is happening.  Most likely you leaving some key information out here, since you code you posted will not lead to this error.

Comment: Does your method declare it returns a "String"?